# Nim-lang (nimrod) fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, nim-lang

I'm learning Nim language. Whenever I try to run the code using this command: `nim c --run hello.nim`,
I get this error:

```sh
Hint: used config file '/etc/nim/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: widestrs [Processing]
Hint: io [Processing]
Hint: hello [Processing]
CC: stdlib_io.nim
CC: stdlib_system.nim
CC: hello.nim
Error: execution of an external compiler program 'gcc -c  -w  -I/usr/lib/nim -I/home/celyes/Scripts/Nim -o /home/celyes/.cache/nim/hello_d/stdlib_io.nim.c.o /home/celyes/.cache/nim/hello_d/stdlib_io.nim.c' failed with exit code: 1

In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/limits.h:34,
                 from /usr/lib/nim/nimbase.h:257,
                 from /home/celyes/.cache/nim/hello_d/stdlib_io.nim.c:9:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/limits.h:194:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
  194 | #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any idea about the solution?

Comment: This is almost certainly the result of some dev package not having been installed. Without knowing the specific Linux distribution, it's difficult to say which (and even then might be guesswork), but the problem is that C compilation breaks because an essential system header file cannot be found.

Comment: There is one more with this issue now: https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/8049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I assume that you did your first test with a tiny Nim program, maybe providing that few lines of code would have not really heart. Well and your Linux distro version and your Nim version would be interesting too, Nim 0.11 way not work that well today :-)

As Nim is a compiled language, it is generally a good idea to separate the compile proces and the program executation process is cases of problems, so that it is obvious if it is a compile error or a runtime error. Your call nim c --run hello.nim would compile and run the program. A plain nim c hello.nim would compile only, so it is absolutely clear that it is compile error. (Indeed in your cases it seems to be obvious that the compile step is the problem, but I have seen issues where it was not so clear...)

But for your actual issue, I have seen such error messages for a few people, and the cause was a problem with the actual linux distro and the way that distro has installed the C compiler incomplete, I think build-essentials was missing. For details see this Nim forum thread

https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/6571

When you can find the actual reason for the issue and it was not your own fault, then you may report it to your distro or maybe even to the Nim github issue tracker, so that such problems can be avoided for newcommers in the future.

And when all works, you are a beginner and want to learn Nim, maybe read

http://ssalewski.de/nimprogramming.html

or some of the other tutorials.